# findItemByText is undefined in typescript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, typescript

i've wrote a function in js that enables/disables telerik RibbonBar's elements.
when i tried to write it again in typescript, i've got an error on the call to the function 'findItemByText'.

```js
///enable / disable elements in the ribbonbar. example (true/false , "RadRibbonBar1", "");
function enableRibbonElement(enbaled_state_bool, ribbonbar_id, elements) {
    var rb = $find(ribbonbar_id);
    for (var i in elements)
        rb.  findItemByText  (elements[i]).set_enabled(enbaled_state_bool);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the call to an undefined function (*findItemByText*), 
but casting to the right telerik element.

First we must include a telerik definitions file (Telerik.Web.UI.d.ts), and then we need to cast the element.
We can do it in different ways:

**1. casting the element when declaring it**

```js
/** enable / disable elements in the ribbonbar. example (true/false , "RadRibbonBar1", "");  */
function enableRibbonElement1(enbaled_state_bool, ribbonbar_id, elements) {
    var rb: Telerik.Web.UI.RadRibbonBar = <any> $find(ribbonbar_id);
    for (var i in elements)
        rb.findItemByText(elements[i]).set_enabled(enbaled_state_bool);
}
```

**2. casting the element to 'any' when working on it**

```js
function enableRibbonElement1(enbaled_state_bool, ribbonbar_id, elements) {
    var rb = $find(ribbonbar_id);
    for (var i in elements)
        (<any>rb).findItemByText(elements[i]).set_enabled(enbaled_state_bool);
}
```

**3. when declaring: avoid casting from other types (number, string) (*thanks to zlumer*):**

```js
/** enable / disable elements in the ribbonbar. example (true/false , "RadRibbonBar1", "");  */
function enableRibbonElement1(enbaled_state_bool, ribbonbar_id, elements) {
    var rb = <Telerik.Web.UI.RadRibbonBar>$find(ribbonbar_id);
    for (var i in elements)
        rb.findItemByText(elements[i]).set_enabled(enbaled_state_bool);
}
```